# splitting strings after certain characters

Tags: python, string, split

I would like to split my string after certain characters are found.

```
identifier = filecontent_id[0].split("SV=")[0]
```

I have this, but this "deletes" everything before `"SV="` and I would like for it to "delete" everything 1 character after it. For example, it would "delete" everything after `"SV=1"` but I did not put 1 there because it doesn't always equal 1. The string is:

```
>tr|A0A024RAP8|A0A024RAP8_HUMAN HCG2009644, isoform CRA_b OS=Homo sapiens GN=KLRC4-KLRK1 PE=4 SV=1MGWIRGRRSRHSWEMSEFHNYNLDLKKSDFSTRWQ
```

and I am trying to only get:

```
>tr|A0A024RAP8|A0A024RAP8_HUMAN HCG2009644, isoform CRA_b OS=Homo sapiens GN=KLRC4-KLRK1 PE=4 SV=1
```

Comment: It doesnt "delete" it. when you do a `split`, the string becomes a list. Then when you do a `[0]` on it, it selects the first element of the list

Comment: @letsc is absolutely right. Did you try printing the value of `filecontent_id[0].split("SV=%s")[0]`?

Comment: Yes I know it doesn't "delete" it I just thought this would get my point across... @letsc

Comment: @ObscureGeek I did do that but like I said, it prints everything before "SV=" (also, I edited my post)

Comment: could you post an example string?

Comment: @ObscureGeek - that would get rid of `SV=` and keep the string after that. Not what the OP wants. He should use split here on `SV=`

Comment: Yes I would like to keep the `SV=` part. But also, I'd want it to keep one character after `SV=`. @ObscureGeek

Comment: @letsc I see the point.

Comment: Look at the answer, I think that is the best way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A regex might be better, but the below works

```
SPLIT="SV="
line=">tr|A0A024RAP8|A0A024RAP8_HUMAN HCG2009644, isoform CRA_b OS=Homo sapiens GN=KLRC4-KLRK1 PE=4 SV=1MGWIRGRRSRHSWEMSEFHNYNLDLKKSDFSTRWQ"
print line.split(SPLIT)[0] + SPLIT + line.split(SPLIT)[1][0]
```

Comment: Yes! That works! That is exactly what I was looking for...regex had given me trouble in the past so I didn't try it again.